# Move UIImage around the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have this code:

```
UIImageView *_propLoading;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"loading" duration:.8f];
    [_propLoading setImage:image];
}
```

This works perfectly, but i need move around screen at the same time

i try this code but not works.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         _propLoading.frame = CGRectMake(22, 33, 134, 232);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];
}
```

Comment: Try `[UIView animateWithView:_propLoading...` ?

Comment: Which method are you putting that animation code in? because if it's in `viewDidLoad` it won't animate. Also, does `_propLoading` have an image before you are moving it? And `_propLoading` is a `UIImageView`, right?

Comment: exactly _propLoading is a UIImageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:_propLoading
                duration:2.0f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
            animations:^{
                _propLoading.frame = CGRectMake(22, 33, 134, 232);
                [_propLoading setImage:image];
            } completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Dont works because its is 2 animations at the same time..... 1 like gif (viewDidLoad) and the other... (viewDidAppear) 2 move around the screen the gif animated

Comment: You can nest a second animation in the 'completion' block of a first :)